# WordPress plugin to allow each author to upload a background image?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a WordPress plugin which lets each author upload a background image for their archive page? My aim is to display both the author's avatar and a background image on the author archive page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/fancier-author-box/ to complete your task

Comment: Hi Waseem, thank you for the link. Using the plugin but how can I let my authors upload a background image? I'd like each background image to display on each author's archive page next to their avatar.

Comment: Dear Henry you can use "Backgroud per page plugin" http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/background-per-page this plugin help you to upload different background images for your Posts, Pages and Authors Archive.
if you face any difficulties to install this plugin or configure this plugin you can contact me via this stack over flow thread...

Comment: I can't see where I can let my author's upload a background for display on their archive page.